# How to detect that all 30 Alamofire requests have all been responded to?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am making an app that shows you the exchange rates between two currencies in the last 30 days by presenting the data in a chart. I am using Alamofire, together with SwiftyJSON to parse the response. The API that I am using is http://fixer.io.

In my view controller, I have this method called `getRate` that will populate a dictionary (`[Date: Double]`) called `rates`. `getRate` will be called in `viewDidLoad` and is defined as follows:

```
func getRate() {
    let baseCurrency = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "baseCurrency")
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    for date in last30Days {
        let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
        let url = "https://api.fixer.io/\(dateString)?base=\(baseCurrency!)&symbols=\(self.currency!)"
        Alamofire.request(url).responseString {
            [weak self]
            response in
            if let _ = response.error {
                return
            }

            let json = JSON(parseJSON: response.value!)
            if let _ = json["error"].string {
                return
            }

            if self != nil {
                if let rate = json["rates"][self!.currency.currencyCode].double {
                    self!.rates[date] = rate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`last30Days` is a constant, of type `[Date]`, storing a `Date` for every day in the last 30 days. `self.currency` is a enum type value passed to this view controller by another view controller. `self.currency.currencyCode` is a computed property that returns the currency code of the currency represented by the enum, e.g. `"GBP"`. Basically, `getRate` is making 30 requests and adding the responses values to the `rates` dictionary.

What I want to do is after all 30 requests have been responded without an error, a chart is plotted according to the exchange rates. Currently, I check if the dictionary has 30 entries. If it does, refresh the chart:

```
var rates: [Date: Double] = [:]
    {
    didSet {
        if rates.count == 30 {
            refreshCharts()
        }
    }
}
```

This worked fine until I want to add a "refresh" button. When the user refreshes, I want to make the same 30 requests again. If they all succeed without error, populate `rates` with the new values. If one or more error occurred, I want to keep the value of `rates` unchanged i.e. keep the old data.

To do this, I must know when all 30 requests have been responded to and whether is any error. I can't use the `if rates.count == 30` trick anymore because when the user refreshes, `rates` is already populated with old values. I can't set `rates` to empty at the beginning because that will lose the old data, which is needed to be displayed when there is any error.  I can't guarantee that will be no errors at the start of `getRate`.

Basically, **how can I know when all 30 requests are responded to and whether any errors occurred**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a DispatchGroup:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()
var errors: [Error] = []

for date in last30Days {
    group.enter()

    // ...

    Alamofire.request(url).responseString {
        defer { group.leave() }
        guard let error = response.error else {
            errors.append(error)
            return
        }

        // ...
    }
}

group.notify(queue: .main) { 
    // All requests are finished now
}
```

Please note that the errors array will not be thread safe (same as your dictionary).

Edit: For thread safety, you can dispatch your updates on a queue to ensure the variables aren't modified from different threads at once.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "queue")
var errors: [Error] = []
for date in last30Days {
    // ...
    queue.async {
        errors.append(error)
    }
    // ...
}
```

You can do the same for your dictionary

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about thread-safety? What can possibly happen?

Comment: I edited the answer to show how you can achieve thread safety. Basically, if you try to write to variable from multiple queues at the same time, some of these writes can be dropped. In your case, only 29 of the 30 values could be present, even though all network requests worked flawlessly.

Comment: Ok, so where should I assign the response value to `self.rates`? In the `group.notify` block? But I can't access the responses there, right?

Comment: You should assign to `self.rates` inside of a `queue.async { }` block. In the `group.notify` block, the rates and the errors collection will be populated correctly